# Chrome scrolling issue

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, xps, scrolling

As we all know, Ubuntu 18.04 has a few scrolling issues.
But I notices something really interesting. In general, I don't have many problems with scrolling. But I have one which is very annoying.
When I scroll in a different application(in my case, it's always reproducible with LibbreOffice), and then quite quickly switch to Chrome and move cursor, the page jumps up or down depending on what direction I was scrolling in LibreOffice.

Comment: Yup, I have noticed the exact same problem. Been looking around, but I can't find any solutions. The bug is reproducible. It seems to me that the scroll position for one application is remembered, so when you then scroll in another application, you jump to the scroll position of the previous app.

Comment: BTW, I can reproduce this with a mouse wheel, but not touch pad.